# How to properly set a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to properly set a one-to-one relationship, please?

User table:

```
[Table("User")]
class User{
 [Key]
 public int idUser;
 public int idComputer; //ForeignKey
}
```

Computer table:

```
[Table("Computer")]
class Computer{
 [Key]
 public int idComputer;
}
```

Comment: So the problem is that the same computer can "belong" to many users?

Comment: @StevenLiekens, to only one user.

Comment: You can't guarantee that a single `idComputer` is used in only one record of `User` though

Comment: User (1) and user (2) can both have computer (1) as their key for `idComputer`. Unless you have a `Unique` field constraint somewhere that you haven't told us about.

Comment: You can have look here Configure One-to-One Relationship

Comment: have a look here :http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one-to-one relationship of User and Computer:

```
public class User
    {
        public User() 
        { 
        }

        public int idUser; { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }


        public virtual Computer Computer{ get; set; }

    }


public class Computer
    {
        public Computer() 
        {
        }
        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
        public int idUser{ get; set; }

        public string ComputerName {get;set;}

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: why using the Key data-annotation?

Comment: for making clear that it is foreign key from User Table

Comment: isn't foreignkey is sufficient?

Comment: Where is idComputer ?

Comment: you dont need to pass IdComputer in User as you have whole object of Coputer there

Comment: and i used to pass Attribute for making things clear

Comment: see this link, you can get a better look:
http://www.joshrharrison.com/archive/2013/04/06/entity-framework-code-first-one-to-one-relationships.aspx

Comment: and this one:http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: how to allow null values on Foreign keys please?

Comment: yes, but, I have this foreign key in sql server as `not null`.

Comment: you have to allow null there as well.

Comment: it is not possible to make from Code first?

Comment: you can make but you have to make change in db as well, if you will create db from code first it will autmatically make it:

public int? UserId  now UseriD is nullable

Answer (score 0):

Referring your code:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
 {
  [Key]
  public int idUser;
  public int idComputer; 
  public virtual Computer Computer;
 } 

[Table("Computer")]
 public class Computer
 {

  [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
  public int idComputer;
  public virtual User User;

 }
```

You can have look here [Configure One-to-One Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad how, it is an example here:http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: how to allow null values on Foreign keys please?